# clarification on the concept of Java thread

Tags: java, multithreading

which is the thread that will begin as soon as the execution of a java program begins?
This was asked in an interview for me. 
so can anyone suggest the answer here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The '**main()**' method in Java is referred to the thread that is running,
>   whenever a Java program runs. It calls the main thread because it is
>   the first thread that starts running when a program begins. Other
>   threads can be spawned from this main thread. The main thread must be
>   the last thread in the program to end. When the main thread stops, the
>   program stops running.
>
> Main thread is created automatically, but it can be controlled by the
>   program by using a Thread object. The Thread object will hold the
>   reference of the main thread with the help of currentThread() method
>   of the Thread class.

for more details check this link

- ['Main' Thread in Java](http://www.go4expert.com/articles/main-thread-java-t4178/)

Comment: Please note that the main thread is not required to quit last. The program stops running when the last non-deamon thread stops, which may, but need not to be the main thread.

Comment: "Main thread...can be controlled by...using a Thread object [...that] will hold the reference of the main thread with the help of currentThread() method of the Thread class."  I think what you are trying to say is that code running in any thread (including the main thread) can get a reference to its own Thread object by calling Thread.currentThread().

Answer (score 4):

From [`Thread`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) API document

> When a Java Virtual Machine starts up, there is usually a single non-daemon thread (which typically calls the method named main of some designated class).

And this thread will be called as main thread.

Answer (score 1):

The thread which is created when you start is called the `main thread`. It is the one which invokes the `main` method.

Edit: apparently someone beat me to the answer.